# trouble running eclipse from usb

Tags: java, eclipse, usb-drive

I am trying to run Eclipse Kepler from a usb drive. It will work when coding but when I come
to run the program it shows

`error = 216. This version of %1 is not compatible with version of windows you are running.`

Eclipse runs fine at home (`windows 8 64bit Java 7`) but the issue happens at college (`Windows server 32bit java 6`) Can anyone shed any light on possible issues please.

The JDK and JRE are installed on the USB device and running Java 7. 32 bit Eclipse is installed to USB also. Is it even possible to run java and eclipse as standalone from a usb?

Comment: Are you trying to run a 64 bit version of the program in a 32 bit machine?

Comment: @Hariprasad No, have installed 32 bit version to usb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code 216 generally means that there is a problem in the 32/64 bit version mismatch between your applications or OS.As you say your eclipse and OS is 32 bit could you please also check if the JDK you are using is 32 bit ?

Comment: It was a 64 bit version I had installed, I never thought to check that, have now installed 32 bit and should work.

Comment: Great , let us know if it does...I have never tried running eclipse from a USB...